Prove That $f = 0$ Almost Everywhere: Struggling with a Challenging $L^1$ Problem
Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose there exists a countable set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $p, q \notin S$, we have:
$$
\int_p^q f(x) \, dx = 0.
$$
I have been trying for a long time to prove that $f = 0$ almost everywhere but have not reached a final result. Here is the closest I’ve gotten so far:
Define the function $F(q) = \int_p^q f(x) \, dx$, where $p$ is any point not in $S$. The function $F(q)$ is continuous on the dense set $S^c$ (the complement of $S$), and it is given that $F(q) = 0$ on $S^c$.
By a theorem, $F(q) = 0$ must hold on all of $\mathbb{R}$.
The theorem: If a function is continuous on a dense set and extends continuously to the whole space, then it must be the unique extension to the entire space. Since $F(q) = 0$ on a dense set, it must be zero everywhere.
If this reasoning works, the rest of the problem seems easy to complete. Specifically, for any $r, p, q \in \mathbb{R}$, the integral $\int_p^q f(x) \, dx = 0$ would imply that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.
I am not entirely confident about this reasoning and would appreciate any help in clarifying or correcting it. Does this approach seem valid? Are there any gaps or missteps in the argument?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Saying $F$ is continuous on $S^c$ is not enough, because even though your $F$ is defined everywhere you still haven’t said that it’s continuous everywhere. Also, even if I ignore this, your next conclusion about the integral vanishing for all $p,q$ isn’t fully justified, because you only considered $p\in S^c$ initially, i.e you need another limiting argument.
So instead, I’d proceed as follows: define $F(p,q)=\int_p^qf$. This is continuous on $\Bbb{R}^2$ by the dominated convergence theorem and vanishes on the dense set $S^c\times S^c$, so by continuity it vanishes on all of $\Bbb{R}^2$. It follows $f=0$ a.e by a more standard version of the problem.

Thank you for your feedback! May you clarify the use of dominated convergence theorem please? So, this will also lead to say for any $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$, the integral $\int_p^q f(x) , dx = 0$ would imply that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

So, to recap, To prove $f = 0$ almost everywhere, we define $F(p, q) = \int_p^q f(x) , dx$, which is a well-defined and continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the dominated convergence theorem. Since $F(p, q) = 0$ on the dense set $S^c \times S^c$, continuity implies $F(p, q) = 0$ for all $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$. This establishes that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.
Alternatively, partition the real line into disjoint sets:
$$
A = {x : f(x) > 0}, \quad B = {x : f(x) < 0}, \quad C = {x : f(x) = 0}.
$$
We show that $\mu(A) = 0$ and $\mu(B) = 0$.
